# How to use web.config connection string in my C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am a newbie in asp.net and web.config files, i have added the connection string to my web.config file like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But now i want to use it in my code file. How will i achieve it?

Comment: [ASP.NET Data Access Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178359(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx) and adjusted:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/YourWebSiteRoot");
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
{
    connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings
                 .ConnectionStrings["StudentConnectionString"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this value by:

```
String connectionString =
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use mine. Make sure you are using Configuration.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Reference System.Configuration dll in your application

```
// Code to read connectionstring

string connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["StudentConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

// Code to read application settings

string settingsValue= ConfigurationManager.ApplicationSettings["Key"];
```